# Given two topologies on a set , prove that the set is finite.

Tags: general-topology

**Problem**

Let $\tau$ be a **finite closed topology** on a set X . If $\tau$ is also the **discrete topology**, prove that the set X is finite.

**Attempt**

Since $\tau$ is a discrete topology ,it contains all its subsets. Also $\tau$  is finite closed topology ,which implies all subsets in $\tau$  has finite complement . Combining these two we get, all the subsets of X have finite complement,i.e., X-S$_i$ = finite for all i.

How to proceed after that ?

Comment: Every subset is the complement of a subset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x \in X$, then $\{x\}$ is open (as $\tau$ is discrete) and so $X\setminus \{x\}$ is finite. Now $X = \{x\} \cup X\setminus \{x\}$ which is still finite.